# How to refresh only a single item in React?

Tags: reactjs, refresh, render, setstate

I've this **App** React component (TypeScript):

```js
class App extends React.Component {

public state = {
    text: ''
}

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'something' };
}

public handleClick = () => {
    const date = `new ! : ${new Date().toString()}`;

    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log('click ! : ' + date);

    this.setState({
        text: date
    });
};

public render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Button</button>
            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
            <Hello />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

And this **Hello** component:

```js
export class Hello extends React.Component {
@lazyInject("nameProvider")
private readonly nameProvider: IProvider<string>;

public render() {
    return <h1>Hello {this.nameProvider.provide()}!</h1>;
}
}
```

Where the `nameProvider` is a simple provider which return based on a random number a string.

When clicking the button, the Date gets updated, however also the **Hello** component is re-rendered each time.

Is this expected? If yes, please explain.

And can this behaviour be changed?

Check full example project [here...](https://github.com/StefH/ReactExamples/tree/master/my-app)

Comment: If I know my react (I probably don't that well), then the process would be: state change in App > render in App which will re-render everything and then compute the diff between the internal DOM and the actual DOM contents and update

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Hello` component a `PureComponent` by extending [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), so that it doesn't re-render on every parent render

```
export class Hello extends React.PureComponent {

    @lazyInject("nameProvider")
    private readonly nameProvider: IProvider<string>;

    public render() {
        return <h1>Hello {this.nameProvider.provide()}!</h1>;
    }

}
```

Comment: purecomponents do a shallow comparison on props so component could be re-rendered, if you want to avoid completely re-renders you have to return always false in shoulsComponentUpdate lifecycle method

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Yes but the Hello Component doesn't receive props and you wouldn't want to stop the Hello component from re-rendering completely.

Comment: or you can use `memo` hence this is relatively easy component